# Sqoop error extraneous input 't1' expecting EOF near '<EOF>'

Tags: hadoop, sqoop

I am trying to import some data from hive cluster to another HDFS cluster with multiple mappers. I am using below command to import data.

/opt/isv/app/pkgs/sqoop-1.4.4.bin__hadoop-1.0.0/bin/sqoop import --connect jdbc:hive://XXXXXX.com:10000/strrecommender --driver org.apache.hadoop.hive.jdbc.HiveDriver -e 'select upc_cd, sltrn_dt, sltrn_id, loc_id, pos_rgstr_id, hh_id from strrecommender.sltrn_dtl_full where TO_DATE(part_dt)>="2011-03-04" AND TO_DATE(part_dt)<"2011-03-11"  AND $CONDITIONS' --target-dir /user/rxg3437/QADataThroughSqoopWeekly/ramesh -m 2 --split-by sltrn_dt

This command is internally generating another query to get min and max dates.

SELECT MIN(sltrn_dt), MAX(sltrn_dt) FROM (select upc_cd, sltrn_dt, sltrn_id, loc_id, pos_rgstr_id, hh_id from strrecommender.sltrn_dtl_full where TO_DATE(part_dt)>="2011-03-04" AND TO_DATE(part_dt)  AND  (1 = 1) ) AS t1

and this query is failing with below error:

14/03/19 11:43:12 ERROR tool.ImportTool: Encountered IOException running import job: java.io.IOException: java.sql.SQLException: Query returned non-zero code: 40000, cause: FAILED: ParseExce
ption line 1:195 extraneous input 't1' expecting EOF near ''

```
    at org.apache.sqoop.mapreduce.db.DataDrivenDBInputFormat.getSplits(DataDrivenDBInputFormat.java:170)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient.writeNewSplits(JobClient.java:1054)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient.writeSplits(JobClient.java:1071)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient.access$700(JobClient.java:179)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient$2.run(JobClient.java:983)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient$2.run(JobClient.java:936)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:396)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1190)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient.submitJobInternal(JobClient.java:936)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job.submit(Job.java:550)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job.waitForCompletion(Job.java:580)
    at org.apache.sqoop.mapreduce.ImportJobBase.doSubmitJob(ImportJobBase.java:186)
    at org.apache.sqoop.mapreduce.ImportJobBase.runJob(ImportJobBase.java:159)
    at org.apache.sqoop.mapreduce.ImportJobBase.runImport(ImportJobBase.java:239)
    at org.apache.sqoop.manager.SqlManager.importQuery(SqlManager.java:645)
    at org.apache.sqoop.tool.ImportTool.importTable(ImportTool.java:415)
    at org.apache.sqoop.tool.ImportTool.run(ImportTool.java:502)
    at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.run(Sqoop.java:145)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:65)
    at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.runSqoop(Sqoop.java:181)
    at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.runTool(Sqoop.java:220)
    at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.runTool(Sqoop.java:229)
    at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.main(Sqoop.java:238)
```

Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Query returned non-zero code: 40000, cause: FAILED: ParseException line 1:195 extraneous input 't1' expecting EOF near ''

```
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.jdbc.HiveStatement.executeQuery(HiveStatement.java:194)
    at org.apache.sqoop.mapreduce.db.DataDrivenDBInputFormat.getSplits(DataDrivenDBInputFormat.java:145)
    ... 23 more
```

Could anyone please help?

Answer (score 0):

You should not use -e to query, instead, using --query. This is the example sqoop official document said:

```
17.3. Example Invocations
   Select ten records from the employees table:
   $ sqoop eval --connect jdbc:mysql://db.example.com/corp \
   --query "SELECT * FROM employees LIMIT 10"

     Insert a row into the foo table:
   $ sqoop eval --connect jdbc:mysql://db.example.com/corp \
     -e "INSERT INTO foo VALUES(42, 'bar')"
```